GRUB Boot Issue on Dell Inspiron 3493: Ubuntu Defaults to shimx64.efi Causing Minimal Bash Like Editing Error
I have a Dell Inspiron 3493 laptop that came with Windows 10, and I upgraded to Windows 11. But after some time, I noticed significant slowdowns with Windows 11, so I switched to Ubuntu, which has been much faster and more efficient on my machine. I installed Ubuntu using a bootable USB drive and followed all steps successfully.However, after 2–3 days, I encountered a boot issue where I get the following message:"Minimal bash-like editing is supported. grub>" I searched for solutions and tried using commands like set root=(hd1,gpt2), but I received the error: "command failed".I then checked the boot settings in my BIOS and noticed that the default boot file was set to shimx64.efi, but it should be grubx64.efi to boot Ubuntu correctly. I manually set grubx64.efi as the default boot file, and everything worked fine for 2 days. However, my laptop keeps automatically switching back to shimx64.efi, and I end up with the same "minimal bash" error again. I did this like 2- 3 times and notice that when i set grubx64.efi as default boot file my laptop works fine, but when my laptop set shimx64.efi as a default file automatically, again the minimal bash like editing is supported error comes back . I even try to update grub using live usb but still same issue again.
Here's what I’ve already checked:
1.Secure Boot is disabled.
2.I’ve reinstalled Ubuntu multiple
times, but the issue persists.
Does anyone have any solutions to prevent Ubuntu from defaulting back to shimx64.efi or permanently fix this GRUB issue?

I have never turned UEFI Secure boot on, and use shimx64.efi to boot. That should not be an issue.  Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  How much RAM and what version of Ubuntu?

RAM : 8GB
Ubuntu Version : ubuntu 22.04 LTS jammy
pastebin link : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sKJ78M2qZS/
is there anything else required, please let me know..

Not really seeing much. You have UEFI system, set to boot in UEFI mode. Fstab has mount of ESP - efi system partition. But you also have grub installed to gpt's protective MBR for old BIOS boot. Make sure UEFI/BIOS is set to boot in UEFI boot mode, not BIOS/Legacy/CSM or combined mode. It is supposed to default to correct mode for boot entry you select, but sometimes it gets confused. When you get grub> does typing "exit" work? or configfile (hd0,2)/boot/grub/grub.cfg

I keep seeing the grub> prompt every 1-2 days, and when I type exit ( grub>exit ), it works. However, I don't know why I keep encountering this grub>  screen so frequently.
Another thing I noticed is that the command set root=(hd1,gpt2) works now, but before running this command, I need to execute insmod lvm. After that, the set root=(hd1,gpt2) command works, and all other commands, including grub>boot, run successfully.
I hope this information helps in diagnosing the issue.
i checked that boot mode is set to uefi only. also my system doesn't support legacy mode.

I did not see lvm in your Boot-Repair report? Do you have LVM? Have seen where even if not using encryption, it can help to install sudo apt install libblockdev-crypto2 libblockdev-mdraid2  while you do not normally edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg does adding the insmod lvm to it near other insmods help? It will get erased with any grub update, kernel update etc. If it does help we have to add it to grub configuration.
